# Transfering a million files from Google Storage to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

We need to copy about a million files from Google Storage bucket (Nearline) to Amazon S3.

The trouble is that Google key created from a refresh token works only a hour. I am afraid that listing all files (which are at a Google Storage bucket) may take more than a hour. Can you help?

Comment: Could you explain more about what the problem is? Any one list call returns only a thousand or so elements and a nextPageToken for more. You can use a new access token to fetch the next page if the old one's expired.